# Quickblox 1:1 chat dialog is not opening

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I configured quickblox successfully, created session and login user working perfect.
but when we create chat dialog then its does nothing.

```
final QBChatDialog dialogToCreate = new QBChatDialog();
    dialogToCreate.setName("xxx xxx ");
    dialogToCreate.setType(QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP);
    dialogToCreate.setUserId(xxx1);

    ArrayList<Integer> occupantsIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    occupantsIds.add(xxx1);
    occupantsIds.add(xxx2);
    dialogToCreate.setOccupantsIds(occupantsIds);


    QBRestChatService.createChatDialog(dialogToCreate).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog qbChatDialog, Bundle bundle) {
            qbChatDialog.initForChat(qbChatDialog.getDialogId(), QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP, QBChatService.getInstance());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

        }
    });
```

Last log i found in this app is below:

```
                                                          '{"session":{"application_id":69154,"created_at":"2018-04-06T10:51:59Z","id":670583149,"nonce":-590011862,"token":"91d65e64a26f33f20dc7d06ec9fb41f111010e22","ts":1523011917,"updated_at":"2018-04-06T10:51:59Z","user_id":44771703,"_id":"670583149"}}'
```

- QBSessionListener onSessionCreated: WITH USER
- D/QBASDK: SubscribeService:  subscribeToPushesAutomatic
- D/QBASDK:QBSessionListener onSessionUpdated
- D/QBASDK: SubscribeService:subscribeToPushesAutomatic
- D/QBASDK: SubscribeService:    SubscribeService created
- D/QBASDK: SubscribeService: onHandleIntent    start: register to pushes  7.
- D/QBASDK: SubscribeService: Your meta-data are not set, auto push subscribe unable
- D/QBASDK: SubscribeService: onHandleIntent start: register to pushes
- D/QBASDK: SubscribeService: Your meta-data are not set, auto push
  subscribe unable  D/QBASDK: SubscribeService: Service onDestroy

Please suggest how to open chat dialog ?

Comment: Add your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Your onError(QBResponseException e) method is empty. try logging there and see if you get any error messages

Comment: implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.8.1"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.8.1"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:3.8.1"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:3.8.1"

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that in manifest file you added given below service and meta-data:

```
<service
 android:name="com.quickblox.messages.services.gcm.QBGcmPushInstanceIDService"
 android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>

<meta-data
        android:name="com.quickblox.messages.TYPE"
        android:value="GCM" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.quickblox.messages.SENDER_ID"
        android:value="@string/sender_id" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.quickblox.messages.QB_ENVIRONMENT"
        android:value="DEVELOPMENT" />
```

Then, after you have to create opponent's list before creating a dialog:

```
    ArrayList<QBUser> qbUserList = new ArrayList<QBUser>();
    QBUser qbUser = new QBUser();
    qbUser.setId(524618);
    qbUser.setFullName("test");

    qbUserList.add(qbUser);
    qbUserList.add(QBChatService.getInstance().getUser());
```

Then after you have to call this method:

```
QBRestChatService.createChatDialog(QbDialogUtils.createDialog(users)).performAsync(
            new QbEntityCallbackWrapper<QBChatDialog>(callback) {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog dialog, Bundle args) {
                    initForChat(dialog); // here i created one method that init chat from dialog
                    super.onSuccess(dialog, args);
                }
            });
```

Before this make sure that you created QBChatService in you oncreate class:

```
chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
```

method for init chat:

```
private void initForChat(QBChatDialog dialog){
 dialog.initForChat(chatService);

 //make sure you defined private ConnectionListener chatConnectionListener; 
chatConnectionListener = new VerboseQbChatConnectionListener(getSnackbarAnchorView()) {
        @Override
        public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
            super.reconnectionSuccessful();

            switch (qbChatDialog.getType()) {
                case GROUP:
                    chatAdapter = null;
                    // Join active room if we're in Group Chat
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            joinGroupChat();
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

group chat method:

```
private void joinGroupChat() {

    ChatHelper.getInstance().join(qbChatDialog, new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void result, Bundle b) {

            loadDialogUsers();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

        }
    });
}
```

Then load dialog users:

```
private void loadDialogUsers() {
    ChatHelper.getInstance().getUsersFromDialog(qbChatDialog, new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> users, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

        }
    });
}
```